# HiveQL converting or synchronizing date types stored in different formats

Tags: datetime, hive, hiveql

I am trying to synchronize two time indicator columns in different tables in preparation for a join. The problem is `date1` in `db1` is in string format with no trailing zeros and `date2` in `db2` is in timestamp format but with trailing zeroes for a date that does not have hours or nanoseconds. I am showing the variables below. How can I synchronize the two? I have tried some suggestions so far but unsuccessfully so. For instance when I use the `cast` `as` `timestamp` conversion for `date1`, I get null for dates with no time information. I show sample data from the table columns below.

```
date1 (string)

2017-05-13 11:46:12
2017-06-17
2017-05-19 05:34:52.78
2017-06-16 12:10:13.177
2017-05-25 05:32:05.99
2017-05-25 06:43:35.007
2017-05-13 11:45:47.873
2017-06-05

date2 (timestamp)

7/18/2013 18:08:48.000000
8/26/2015 00:00:00.000000
5/7/2015 20:03:25.000000
8/16/2014 12:08:48.000000
3/17/2017 11:05:52.530000
1/9/2014 21:11:49.000000
6/16/2016 14:22:40.157000
5/5/2017 14:12:48.497000
```

Comment: This does not make sense. if `date2` would have been of timestamp type then this wouldn't be its string representation.

Comment: The tables obviously have gone through changes. For instance, data1 is a copy of a timestamp and has undergone transformation along the way into a string through a process which is not in my control. I will edit the post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

date1

```
with    t as 
        (
            select  explode
                    (
                        array
                        (
                            '2017-05-13 11:46:12'
                           ,'2017-06-17'
                           ,'2017-05-19 05:34:52.78'
                           ,'2017-06-16 12:10:13.177'
                           ,'2017-05-25 05:32:05.99'
                           ,'2017-05-25 06:43:35.007'
                           ,'2017-05-13 11:45:47.873'
                           ,'2017-06-05'
                        )
                    )   as date1
        )
select  cast(date1 as timestamp)
from    t
;
```

---

```
2017-05-13 11:46:12
2017-06-17 00:00:00
2017-05-19 05:34:52.78
2017-06-16 12:10:13.177
2017-05-25 05:32:05.99
2017-05-25 06:43:35.007
2017-05-13 11:45:47.873
2017-06-05 00:00:00
```

date2

```
with    t as 
        (
            select  explode
                    (
                        array
                        (
                            '7/18/2013 18:08:48.000000'
                           ,'8/26/2015 00:00:00.000000'
                           ,'5/7/2015 20:03:25.000000'
                           ,'8/16/2014 12:08:48.000000'
                           ,'3/17/2017 11:05:52.530000'
                           ,'1/9/2014 21:11:49.000000'
                           ,'6/16/2016 14:22:40.157000'
                        )
                    )   as date2
        )
select  cast(printf('%04d-%02d-%02d %s',int(d2[2]),int(d2[0]),int(d2[1]),d2[3]) as timestamp)
from    (select split(date2,'[/ ]') as d2 from t) t
;
```

---

```
2013-07-18 18:08:48
2015-08-26 00:00:00
2015-05-07 20:03:25
2014-08-16 12:08:48
2017-03-17 11:05:52.53
2014-01-09 21:11:49
2016-06-16 14:22:40.157
```

Comment: Hi Dudu, thank you so much for your effort. Why do you have the date lists under array? I gave those an an example to show the formats, the actual dates are contained in the columns. I attempted to include the actual date column name and database name and I got a lot of nulls. Is that how I could be doing it? Here is what I did: with    t as 
        (
            select  event_date as date1 from db1.tbl1
        )
select  cast(date1 as timestamp)
from    t

Comment: I also attempted the first code itself to see how I can decode it. It looks like I get a null (?) for the second date. Also tested the second one. The trailing zeros are not trimmed in the result.

Comment: (1) Exploding an array is just a fast way to generate a data set with a single column (2) You can ignore the WITH clause and work directly against your real table. (3) If you get NULLs it means you have time stamps in different formats than those you gave here as an example (or it is originally NULL values) (4) A timestamp is a timestamp. It does not matter how it is represented by your client application (with trailing zeros or not)